# Not getting value from the bean in unit test

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, maven, apache-camel

I have a camel route that looks like this:

```
 <camel:camelContext id="context" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <propertyPlaceholder id="camelContextProperties" location="ref:lefrogen"/>
        <contextScan/>
        <template id="producerTemplate"/>
        <route id="chibzo">
            <from uri="activemq:queueName"/>
            <to uri="seda:internal?multipleConsumers=true"/>
        </route>
        <route id="chon">
            <from uri="seda:internal?multipleConsumers=true"/>
            <bean ref="beanName"/>
            <to uri="seda:external?multipleConsumers=true"/>
        </route>
    </camel:camelContext>
```

The bean class is like this:

```
@Component
public class BeanName {
    private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(BeanName.class.getName());
    public static String message =null;
    public static String map(String custom) {

        message = custom;
        return custom;
    }       

}
```

I have written a unit test case which should call the map method, fetch the data from seda:external, and compare the values of map methos and the seda:external. Right now, I am having a problem where if I execute my test case using mvn test, I have a logger in my test class which prints out the value of the map method. The method is however returning null eventhough I am sending something to the queue. Here's the unit test:

```
public class Test{
@EndpointInject
  ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

  @Autowired
 BeanName beanName; 
 @Test
 public void testName() throws Exception {   
       producerTemplate.sendBody("seda:internal","Good bye");
        String message = beanName.message;
        LOGGER.info("Printing" + message);
}
```

Can someone tell me why I am getting null ?

Comment: Seems like a timing issue. SEDA is asynchronous (and you're calling it in an asynchronous way). So it's unlikely that beanName.map() will be called before you try to get the message. You could put a sleep in there... or re-structure this to get a mock in there and wait until the mock assertions are satisfied.

Comment: Mhhh..that might be the case. Thanks for pointing that out. Will look into it.

Comment: When you say put a sleep in there, do you mean like context.sleep() ?

Comment: I've updated my answer with an explanation. I'd use Thread.sleep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a timing issue.

### What is going on?

[SEDA](http://camel.apache.org/seda.html) is asynchronous (and you're calling it in [an asynchronous way](http://camel.apache.org/producertemplate.html)). This means that as soon as you send your message to the SEDA queue, you move on a process the next statement (where you're grabbing the message value).

As a result, it is highly unlikely that `beanName.map()` will be called before you try to get the message. The more likely scenario is that you get the message and some time later the `map` method is called to actually assign the message.

### How to fix it?

Do what do you do about it? You have a few options.

The least intrusive approach would be to add a `Thread.sleep(..)` after sending the message and before getting it from the bean.

You could use [`adviceWith`](http://camel.apache.org/advicewith.html) to swap out a [`direct`](http://camel.apache.org/direct.html) endpoint for the SEDA one and call it with `reqeustBody` instead of `sendBody`.

Or, if you still want to test the asynchronous calls, you can advice a [mock endpoint](http://camel.apache.org/mock.html) after the bean (perhaps in place of the call to `seda:external`). You can set assertions on the mock and wait (with a timeout) until the mock assertions are satisfied, using something like `mock.assertIsSatisfied(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`